# Expansions and Compressions/Translation of $2y=f(3x-6)-2$

Tags: graphing-functions

Given the graph of $2y=f(3x-6)-2$, is it correct to assume that there is a vertical compression by a factor of 2, a horizontal expansion by a factor of $1/3$, a translation of 2 units right and 2 units down?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is indeed correct.